# How can I properly debug a faulty 22.04 LTS Server autoinstall done with the new subiquity frame?

Tags: server, grub2, desktop-environments, cloud-init, subiquity

**edit2:** Over the 2 weeks with subiquity and cloud-init, I pieced together a new **shell script** with example user-data file and an altered `grub.cfg` as the one by covertsh did not work for me any longer due to removal of isolinux as part of 21.10. The script is automated to repack the ISO to boot on EFI and MBR systems alike and can be acquired [here](https://github.com/PaxJaromeMalues/ubuntu-server-autoinstall-iso-repacker).
Some of the scripts content comes from this thread: [Remaster Installation Image for Ubuntu 20.10](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1289400/remaster-installation-image-for-ubuntu-20-10)

**edit: Sorry if this sounds overly angry, but that is lit. what I feel the last days fighting against subiquity.**

following the order in which I did stuff:

**1**. download daily live server ISO (jammy 22.04 ~1,4Gb)

**2**. unpack iso to a folder

**3**. remove the [BOOT] directory

**4**. some dd magic to get efi and legacy partitions from the ISO file (boot_hybrid)

**5**. write a user-data file, check that file against the schema using cloud-init

**6**. place user-data and empty meta-data file into a new directory in ISO-root named server

**7**. place new grub.cfg with new menuentry in /cdrom/boot/grub/

**8**. use xorriso to repack the iso into a new file
9. Make VM and boot the whole stuff

Now the following thing confuses me:

The installer seems to recognise the new entries in GRUB and acts accordingly, also accepting my entry to open only the network section as interactive and the initial identity section as well.

BUT after the installation the installer seems to have used LVM instead direct method for storage and non of the late commands and also the one user-data runcmd command are executed. All the packages configured under apt are missing as well.

**What would be the necessary steps to debug this situation?**

My first guess was /var/log/subiquity.log, but I had no chance to understand or chronologically follow any of that gibberish output in there.

**Update 1**:

So far, shockingly, none of the related logs were able to offer ANY computable information for why the installer acted the way it did. The only thing supplied are some deeply confusing information about actions within the cloud-init itself neither connected to any input or output that could establish a foundation for actual debugging. Frankly put, the output design is unacceptable.

**Update 2**:
the only thing I was able to find (in an unrelated log to that) is:
[image: ShortCap of journal]

Which leads me to believe, that there has been made a change to probably grub, the autoinstall key or subiquity that has not been documented very well or, which is probably the most likely, I must have made documentation errors somewhere inbetween 20.04 or 21.x and now, on the other hand I documented my trials pretty well and it did work like that before. and I just figured stacks markdown does not support strike through.

**Update 3**:
so far I have managed to get past grub errors and into the actual autoinstall, which still starts to fail at installing the package `ubuntu-desktop-minimal`

Hints for others I can give so far:

- Forget the logs, those are close to (but not entirely) garbage
- Make sure to follow the yaml schema EXACTLY a single space can result in a green light from cloud-init schema check but result in a faulty autoinstall as the OS will omit the file as incorrectly formatted going (without any hint to you) for a default user-data file somewhere in the ISO. I just had enough of going to search for where that is.
- Make sure to duplicate grub.cfg in your iso over loopback.cfg no idea whose idea that was but it's there even if nearly no one needs it.
- some of `grub.cfg` needs to look like this

```
        menuentry "Autoinstall Ubuntu Server + Desktop + Ordersprinter" {
            set gfxpayload=keep
            linux   /casper/vmlinuz quiet autoinstall "ds=nocloud;s=/cdrom/nocloud/" ---
            initrd  /casper/initrd
    }
```

- casper/vmlinuz(tab)quiet < make sure to get that right or the autoinstall starts throwing errors.
- grub did not throw an error, which apparently is not an error but a redirection of the autoinstall keys to the userspace. But hey. Let's format that message as an error, who cares.

**Update 4**:
The installation log of ubuntu itself seems to sometimes actually contain a wee bit of good information!
After 200 lines of confusing stuff you might hit a section called `traceback` if you are lucky enough it tells you what part of the cloud-config actually caused a failure. But sometimes even that section only contains rubbish. But its a start. Honestly `traceback` should be the first thing in that log, not hidden somewhere deep inside.

**Update 5**: Can confirm now that the `ubuntu-desktop-minimal` package is the point where the install halts the entire installation and even if not very reliable the CPU usage by the VM is near zero, same for vdisk IO. Later I will try to install the package via the late commands.
**Update 6**:
why can this [user](https://gist.github.com/dbkinghorn/c236aea31d76028b2b6ccdf6d3c6f07e) use  `sudo` for `tee`, but I can not use `sudo` via `curtin` to run `apt` in `-q -y`?

Comment: The comments are our channel to ask for clarification. Please edit your question and add all additional details in your question and delete your comments.

Comment: @user68186 are those tags better? What else can I do to grab more attention?

Comment: Would be interesting, and helpful[?], to know what you're trying to achieve here? This https://askubuntu.com/q/1394441/29073 appears possibly to be related in suggesting there is a bug in Subiquity with embedded user data. FWIW I've never heard of subiquity nor curtin before; I only say that to indicate that IMO this is more niche than most questions here.

Comment: First and foremost my question was how to debug this whole situation properly. But I already advanced past that point. It seems that the subiquity installer delivered with my daily 22.04 LTS Server ISO was somehow faulty as when I allowed the installer via user-data to update itself, the installation went smoothly. But that was pure luck. Nothing in the logs I was able to locate hinted towards any of that.